# Why are global variables defined within a foreach loop not available to functions called thereafter?

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing

In R, global variables are normally accessible to functions even when they are not passed as arguments:

```
# fn that expects a global variable to exist
func = function() {
  return(globalVar + 2)
}

# outside the scope of a foreach loop
# this obviously works
globalVar = 2
func()
```

But it seems that within a `foreach` loop, one has to use superassignment of the global variable in order for the function to have access to it:

```
# in foreach loop
# this breaks
rm(globalVar)
rs = foreach( i = 1:2, .combine=rbind ) %dopar% {
  globalVar = 2
  data.frame( y = func() )
}  


# in foreach loop, but with superassignment of globalVar
rs = foreach( i = 1:2, .combine=rbind ) %dopar% {
  globalVar <<- 2
  data.frame( y = func() )
} 
rs
```

And yet a regular for-loop does not require superassignment:

```
# in for loop instead of foreach loop; regular assignment again
# this works again
rm(globalVar); rm(rs)
for( i in 1:2 ) {
  globalVar = 2
  new.row = data.frame( y = func() )
  
  if ( i == 1 ) rs = new.row else rs = rbind(rs, new.row)
} 
rs
```

I found little information about the scoping rules of `foreach` when reading its docs. **What is special about the scoping rules of `foreach` that causes this behavior?**

Comment: You have to think of "foreach" as an "lapply", not a for loop.

Comment: In order to run in parallel, `foreach()` has to copy all the data to the different threads. You should not be updating global scope in each thread because then you can have problems with race conditions (multiple threads trying to update the same variable at the same time). You should refactor your code to make proper use of closures to prevent that problem in the first place especially when trying to run in parallel.

Comment: @MrFlick, I think you mean "processes" instead of "threads" - R doesn't parallelize using threads. Processes don't share memory, whereas threads may. Since the parallel workers run in individual processes, they can *not* update or assign variables in the main process. The only way you can pass information back from workers to the main R session is via the return value. That's what F. Privé mean by thinking of it as `lapply()`.

Comment: @HenrikB. Yes. Thank you.